# How to re-run multiple functions in JS on button click?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below, I'm generating random parts of a URL and that spits out an image from **[placeimg.com](https://placeimg.com)**. However, I'm trying to re-run the functions that generate the different parts of the URL, so I can generate a new image on click.

I'm using this:

```
getNewImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  getRandomCat();
  getImageId();
});
```

...but it's not reloading the image. Is the reload() method better here? I don't want to reload the page, I only wan to reload the image.

```js
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.random-image');

//categories
const categories = ['animals', 'arch', 'nature', 'people', 'tech'];
const getRandomCat = function() {
  return categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
}

//image id
function getImageId() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000) + 1;
}

const genImg = document.createElement('img');
genImg.setAttribute('src', `https://placeimg.com/640/480/${getRandomCat()}?t=${getImageId()}`);

//image generated
console.log(`Image: ${genImg.getAttribute('src')}`);

getNewImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  getRandomCat();
  getImageId();
});

imageContainer.appendChild(genImg);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="getNewImage">New Image</button>
<div class="random-image"></div>
```

Comment: Replace the `src` attribute on the image?

Comment: Replace it with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the two functions, but you aren't doing anything with their return values.

Just use the same code you used when setting the image's `src` property on page load in the `click` event handler.

```js
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.random-image');

//categories
const categories = ['animals', 'arch', 'nature', 'people', 'tech'];
const getRandomCat = function() {
  return categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
}

//image id
function getImageId() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000) + 1;
}

const genImg = document.createElement('img');
genImg.setAttribute('src', `https://placeimg.com/640/480/${getRandomCat()}?t=${getImageId()}`);

//image generated
console.log(`Image: ${genImg.getAttribute('src')}`);

getNewImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  genImg.setAttribute('src', `https://placeimg.com/640/480/${getRandomCat()}?t=${getImageId()}`);
});

imageContainer.appendChild(genImg);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="getNewImage">New Image</button>
<div class="random-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call the functions alone but set the src attribute of the image again, see this working snippet:

```js
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.random-image');

//categories
const categories = ['animals', 'arch', 'nature', 'people', 'tech'];
const getRandomCat = function() {
  return categories[Math.floor(Math.random() * categories.length)];
}

//image id
function getImageId() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000000) + 1;
}



const genImg = document.createElement('img');
genImg.setAttribute('src', `https://placeimg.com/640/480/${getRandomCat()}?t=${getImageId()}`);

//image generated
console.log(`Image: ${genImg.getAttribute('src')}`);

getNewImage.addEventListener('click', function() {
  genImg.setAttribute('src', `https://placeimg.com/640/480/${getRandomCat()}?t=${getImageId()}`);
});

imageContainer.appendChild(genImg);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="getNewImage">New Image</button>
<div class="random-image"></div>
```